# Dynamically add return false to all anchors with # (with javascript or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following menu in HTML:

At this point I have *hardcoded* the `onclick="return false"` right in the HTML (see below). I've read that this is bad practice. I would like to know how to add `return false` (or e.preventdefault) to all anchors that have a href of # with jquery and/or javascript.

```
<div id="bar" >
<label id="toggle-label" for="toggle-1">Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
    <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Item with sub</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Sub 1.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/something">Sub 1.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Item with sub-sub</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/something">service-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Item with sub</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/something">sub sub 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/something">sub sub 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/something">sub sub 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/electrical">Electrical</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

                <li><a href="/pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve with returning false on the link?  I know that cancels the action, but you did not explain what issue allowing the link to go through causes.

Comment: When this menu is viewed on small screens, a click on e.g. _Item with sub_ will make the page scroll to the top because of the `#` in the anchor-tag.

Comment: Ok, then the next question would be what is the purpose of making these elements links if they are going to not do anything?

Comment: Good question. Only the _Item with sub_ and _Item with sub-sub_ are supposed to have a  `#`. The rest are supposed to go to e.g. `/contact` and such.

Comment: I think you're missing my point.  You're putting anchor markup in your page, but are effectively killing them from doing anything.  The only potential reason you'd do that would be if you were using the anchor tags to match some sort of default css styling on the page for links.  In which case, rather than "fixing" the links, it would most likely be a better approach to not make them links, and use css to style them to however you want them to look.

Comment: You seem to be missing _my_ point. I've changed the _example_ above to demonstrate that only a few menu-items get a href of #. Only those get killed.

Comment: So only those would be the ones that would not be links, thus removing the need to kill them in the first place.  You have yet to state why all the lis must absolutely, without exception, always be links.  Even the ones that should never function as a link

Comment: I have seen many tutorials that teach to set the `href` of an `a` element to # if it's just a parent-item that isn't supposed to link anywhere, but only acts as a button to show it's children. For example when you make a menu in Wordpress.

Comment: That still does not answer **why** you are forcing the elements to be links in the first place.  Setting the href="#" is a valid case if you are going to attach in page logic to them, so say you click a parent link, and as a result you have javascript that reveals nested sub logic, or something like that.  That makes **sense**.  There is a reason there.  In this case, there is no reason expressed why these must be links in your markup.  You are not attaching any extra logic to them.  The only extra logic you are attaching is to kill them as links.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  That is a valid case for using the href = #.  But again, your logic *is not doing that*.  It's not using the links at all.

Comment: Have you seen that I changed the code in my question to show that my menu **does** have actual links?

Comment: We're not talking about the real links.  We're talking about the href="#" links.  Just because you have real links doesn't mean *everything* must be a link.  I don't understand why you keep referring to the real links.

Comment: Good. Are you suggesting I change the parent-items from `a` to a `div` or something?

Comment: Yes.  A div or span or something.  You may not event need a parent tag.  The `li` being the parent for the non-real links may be enough.  I'm just wanting to make sure you realize what is going on and determine if you actually need those non-real `a` tags in the first place.  If you don't, this question about a fix is unnecessary, :)

Comment: Ok, something to think about. However, as far as I know it's **very normal practice** to make **all** the items in your `li`'s `a`'s, just for the sake of styling them alltogether in css. If you add `span` or `div` you have to style those seperately. The menu's that dynamically get created by Wordpress don't even have the option to make non-`a` menu-items. Literally the first site that I open has non-linking-parent-menu-items with `a` and a #: https://www.canva.com/create/restaurant-menu

Comment: That doesn't make it a good practice.  There are many poorly designed websites in existance.  And to further this point, the majority of websites do not take into account how the markup on their websites will (not) work with screen readers, and other accessibility programs, that users who have issues with sight or mobility rely on to be able to use their websites.  Having fake links on a page that do nothing is a very quick way to confuse these programs and make websites less accessible to these users.

Comment: Next time I have the opportunity to make a menu by hand (and don't have to deal with dynamically created menu's with `a href`'s with #), I will think about what you said. By the way, the `a` makes the browser change the cursor to a hand. That would be another thing that has to be mimiced with css `cursor:hand`.

Comment: Not a hard thing to do with CSS.

Comment: Ok, you've conviced me. I indeed don't like the fact that I have `a`'s in my menu that aren't actually links and which functionality I have to kill with extra and strange javascript from which I don't really know what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select all anchors with `href='#'` using jQuery selector, then add a `onclick` listener to them.

```js
var anchors = $("a[href='#']")
anchors.on("click", (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault(); 
  console.clear()
  console.log("anchor clicked");
  return false
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar" >
<label id="toggle-label" for="toggle-1">Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item with sub</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Sub 1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub 1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item with sub-sub</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">service-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item with sub</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub sub 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub sub 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Electrical</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work great. What's the difference between `return false` and `preventDefault()` if I may ask?

Comment: return false does prevent default, and stop propagation.  So really the prevent default call is unnecessary

Comment: yes, it's almost the same, use just one of those, I added both just as examples of usage.

Comment: @Taplar Is `return false` like the php-functions exit(); and/or die();? So that it stops all further code?

Comment: No, die affects the entire script running.  return false only affects the event currently being processed.

Answer (score 1):

its very simple you can try this

you need to not only try but also understand and try to do different from this.

```js
$('a[href="#"]').click(function (event) {
        return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar" >
  <label id="toggle-label" for="toggle-1">Menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
      <ul class="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Item with sub</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Sub 1.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub 1.2</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Item with sub-sub</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">service-1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Item with sub</a>
                          <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">sub sub 1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">sub sub 2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">sub sub 3</a></li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Electrical</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>

                  <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>

      </ul>

  </div>
```

Comment: then do this a[href="#"]' its simple dude

Answer (score 0):

`$('li a[href="#"]').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});`

You can try this.